# probability density function and expected value of Y

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Consider a random variable Y whose probability density function (PDF) is given by

In integral

$$
f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
\frac43 y^3 & 0 < y < 1 \\
\frac83 - \frac43 y & 1 < y < 2
\end{cases}
$$

$$
E(Y) = \int_{y=0}^2 y \, f_Y(y) \, dy
$$

First term between 0 and 1:

$$
\int_{y=0}^1 y \, \frac43 y^3 \, dy = \frac{4}{15}
$$

Second term between 1 and 2:

$$
\int_{y=1}^2 y \, \left(\frac83 - \frac43 y \right) \, dy = \frac89
$$

$$
E(Y)= \frac{52}{45} = 1.15
$$

Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: This is unreadable to me, please rewrite this using the appropriate syntax

Comment: For example $\int$ is written using \int between two dollar signs

Comment: Other than rounding the last term, this looks good to me!

Comment: OP: I've edited it to use MathJax.  Please check to see that the edit makes sense.  (I think it does, because your computation appears to be valid.)

Comment: Thank you Brian.  and thanks to all for the answers